# Global queries in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

**Controller:**

```
$categories = Categories::get();
return view('coolpage', ['categories' => $categories]);
```

**Blade View:**

```
<ul>
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    <li><a href="{{ secure_url($category->alias) }}">{{ $category->title }}</a></li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

This works perfect on individual views.

I want to be able to have these categories show up on every page (this will be used as a dropdown menu in the header navbar). I have `app.blade.php` that contains the header html and `@yield('content')`. The only way I can think of querying out the categories is somehow putting it in my routes files... which I'm pretty sure is not the way to go.

I'm hoping to get suggestions / examples.

Comment: @Fahad, I don't see the need to clutter up my question. I'm just looking to achieve the same capabilities I have for individual routes on a more global scale. I essentially want to be able to run `Categories::get()` on every route.

Comment: do you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [the Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers), you can use a wildcard view composer to accomplish this.

First you would set up a [service provider](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/providers) for view composers, with a closure-based composer that will apply to every page (the `*` wildcard symbol):

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('*', function($view)
        {
            //
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Then you'll need to add the service provider to the `providers` array in config/app.php. This will register this service provider so that the view composer is called on every page load.

Then you can bind a collection of all `Categories` to all views by adding it to the wildcard view composer like so:

```
public function boot()
{
    View::composer('*', function($view)
    {
        $view->with('categories', \App\Categories::all());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use Laravel [View Composers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers) to bind data to a view.

Answer (score 0):

all, what @jakeOpena says is true, View Composers is the best solution.

here is my example from route.php :

```
View::composer('layouts.left_navbar_menu', function($view) {
 $menu = App::make('LeftNavMenu')->menuBilder();
 $view->with('name', $menu);
});
```

my view "layouts/left_navbar_menu" is included in master template, like this:

```
@include('layouts.boot_left_navbar_menu')
```